# Nextjs 13 get locale from server component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to get locale from component without using 'use client'. Is it possible with nextjs 13 with app router?

```
import en from '@/public/locales/en.json';
import ru from '@/public/locales/ru.json';
    const Header = () => {
       const router = useRouter();
       const {locale} = router;
       const t = locale === 'en' ? en : ru;
       return <div>{t.title}</div>
    }

    const nextConfig = {
        i18n: {
            locales: ['en', 'ru']
        }
    }
```

It gives an error "useRouter only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it". 'use client' solve this. How to get locale code, example 'en' to get locale from local file?

Comment: How is this internalization set up, like file structure and everything? Can you show it?

Comment: Your `page.js` component gets passed the local as part of `params` normally. You can pass it as `props` to `Header`.

Comment: This is solution to pass params everytime if required, because translation is used in 90% of components

Comment: I'm not sure there is another way as of now. Feel free to raise an issue on their GitHub page.

Comment: does this post help https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If anyone still need it, you can use `{useLocale} from "next-intl"` and use it inside your server component.

```js
import { useLocale } from "next-intl/server";
    
export default function ServerComponent() {
    const locale = useLocale()
      
    return (
      <div>{locale}</div>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `useLocale` is a client hook, You can't use it in a server component. and It's imported from "next-intl" not "next-intl/server"

Comment: `useLocale` is a client hook, You can't use it in a server component. and It's imported from "next-intl" not "next-intl/server"

Answer (score 0):

you can import `getLocale` from `"next-intl/server"` and use it inside your server component

```js
import { getLocale } from "next-intl/server";

export default function Home() {
  const locale = getLocale();
  return (
     <main>
       <div>{locale}</div>
     </main>
   );
}
```

Comment: this do not work for me using lastest version of next and next-intl, it seems next-intl/server do not export getLocale